# Understanding a recursive function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a fairly simple question that will help my understanding of recursion. I am following a tutorial on [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/use-recursion-to-create-a-countdown) - *Use recursion to create a countdown*. The below code was used to churn the following list of numbers: `[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]`

```
function countup(n){
    if (n < 1){
        return [];
    } else {
        const countArray = countup(n - 1);
        countArray.push(n);
        return countArray
    }
};

console.log(countup(5)); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I just want to understand, why use `(n-1)` in `const countArray`? I tried and it brought an error, but a better reason would be why? Got to do with indexing where the start is from 0 (I think)?

However, my major question is with `countArray.push(n)`. In my mind, this function is to output in the following order:

```
5,
4,
3,
2,
1
```

...and then the `push` function simply puts them in a list [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] but the answer I get is in the other way round --[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Is it because [push](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-push/) will take the last number from (n-1) rather than the first calculated `n` ie (6-1 = 5, 5-1= 4..., and so on)? As far as I know `push()` adds items to the end of an array.

Understanding the above will clear my confusion on how the below code worked, from the same freecodecamp tutorial:

```
console.log("\nrecursive")
function countdown(n){
    if (n < 1){
        return []
    } else {
        const array = countdown(n - 1);
        array.unshift(n)  //unshift() add to the beginning of an array
        return array  
    }
};

console.log(countdown(5)); \\[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Comment: by the way, for simpler code, since the `if` condition returns, no need for `else` at all

Comment: The reason why the `countup()` is generating the array in the opposite sequence of what you are expecting is because the array is being updated *after* `countup()` is being called recursively, not before. So, it is being called as `countup(5)`, `countup(4)`, `countup(3)`, `countup(2)`, `countup(1)`, `countup(0)`, and *only then* the functions start returning, so, as a result, `countup(0)` returns `[]`, then, as a result, `countup(1)` returns `[1]`, then `countup(2)` returns `[1, 2]` as a consequence, and so on. If you use a debugger to follow the code execution, you could see that happening.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK still trying to understand recursive but your response of using debugger is at least helpful. Lastly, why the n-1 in `countup(n-1)` is it due to indexing as I had suggested? Just want to be sure if I've got a good foundation on this.

Comment: The n-1 is because it is first stacking the values backwards into the call stack, and only then, after it reaches the stop condition (`n < 1`), it starts building the result array.